How do I call the multi-Tkinter window from the Tkinter menu?
My code runs perfectly for displaying a window when a button is clicked, but I would like to control multiple windows using Tkinter. Could you please provide me with some ideas on how to call multiple windows using a menu with grab_set()?

from tkinter import Tk, Menu
from tkinter import *

class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.master = master
        self.my_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.my_frame.pack()

        self.button1 = Button(self.master, text="Open New Window", command = self.open_toplevel_window)
        self.button1.pack()
        
        self.text = Text(self.master, width = 20, height = 3)
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.insert(END, "Before\ntop window\ninteraction")
        
    def open_toplevel_window(self):
        self.top = Toplevel(self.master)
        #this forces all focus on the top level until Toplevel is closed
        self.top.grab_set() 
        
        def replace_text():
            self.text.delete(1.0, END)
            self.text.insert(END, "Text From\nToplevel")
        
        top_button = Button(self.top, text = "Replace text in main window",
                            command = replace_text)
        top_button.pack()
        top_button2 = Button(self.top, text = "------------------w",
                            command = self.open_toplevel_window1)
        top_button2.pack()
        





How do I call the multi-Tkinter window from the Tkinter menu?  but I would like to

control multiple windows using Tkinter.


The problem can be fixed.
Add this to the end:
Snippet:
from tkinter import Tk, Menu
from tkinter import *

class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.master = master
        self.my_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.my_frame.pack()

        self.button1 = Button(self.master, text="Open New Window", command = self.open_toplevel_window)
        self.button1.pack()
        
        self.text = Text(self.master, width = 20, height = 3)
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.insert(END, "Before\ntop window\ninteraction")
        
    def open_toplevel_window(self):
        self.top = Toplevel(self.master)
        #this forces all focus on the top level until Toplevel is closed
        self.top.grab_set() 
        
        def replace_text():
            self.text.delete(1.0, END)
            self.text.insert(END, "Text From\nToplevel")
        
        top_button = Button(self.top, text = "Replace text in main window",
                            command = replace_text)
        top_button.pack()
        top_button2 = Button(self.top, text = "------------------w",
                            command = self.open_toplevel_window)
        top_button2.pack()

        
root = Tk()
app = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()

Screenshot:



